# How to change the executable name on publish in .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-interface

**to demonstrate i will use illustrative names.**

- I use VSCode

### The problem

I have a project with name `App`.

I i enter on my terminal and type: `dotnet publish --configuration Release -o build`

i will have an exe `./build/App.exe`.

this is the current behavior.

### The wanted solution

So, i need the executable name to be `cli.exe` when i run the publish command instead of `App.exe`.

How can i do that?

I have been tried the:

```xml
<TargetName>cli</TargetName>
```

but this tag only changes the `.dll` file, not the `.exe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `TargetName` use `AssemblyName`